# Javascript: textContent based on textLength

Tags: javascript

Hi all (first poster so don't shoot me...yet):

I'm trying to alter a textarea based on the textlength.

My code is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function addComment(){
                var commentBank = document.getElementById("commentBank");
                var selectedComment = commentBank.options[commentBank.selectedIndex].text;
                var currentComment = document.getElementById("comment");

                console.log(currentComment.textLength);

                if(currentComment.textContent == "Add comment here" ){
                    currentComment.textContent = selectedComment;
                }else if(currentComment.textLength == 0){
                    console.log("Trying to add "+selectedComment);
                    currentComment.textContent = "selectedComment";
                }
                else{
                currentComment.textContent += ". " + selectedComment;
                }


            }
            </script>
```

What I'm trying to do is get the selected item from a option (called commentBank), from this, get the text selected and add it to a textarea (called comment).

The issue at present is that when currentComment.textContent () is equal to 0, it doesn't add the text to the textarea.
It does output to the log however, doesn't update the textarea to add the text, so the if statement is working.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **value** instead of **textContent**, to write the content of a textarea.

I don't know all browsers, but in some of them, textContent is read only.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code snippet you're talking about:

```
        }else if(currentComment.textLength == 0){
            console.log("Trying to add "+selectedComment);
            currentComment.textContent = "selectedComment";
```

The reason it doesn't actually *add* the comment is because you are setting `currentComment.textContent` to the *string* `"selectedComment"`, not the *value*. That's why it prints okay in your log (because you're logging the value). Change that line to:

```
currentComment.textContent = selectedComment;
```

(Note the absence of the quotation marks, which creates a string with the literal value `selectedComment`.)

Comment: Thanks @Josh, I've altered the code but to no avail, I had played around with it prior asking on here, and both versions did not alter the text.
Any other ideas?

Comment: It seems to be working as expected for me: http://jsfiddle.net/joshleitzel/9LRN6/ Is that basically what you're intending to happen?

Comment: once you delete the text from the text box and select an element it won't add any.

It appears .value is working. 

Thanks to you both for your quick responses